# Is there a findall in Scala maps?

Tags: scala, find

In a Scala Map, how do I get all keys in a Map that have the same value?

For example in my Map I have 3 keys which have the value 27

Eg:

```
large -> 27
indispensable -> 27
most -> 27
```

I tried

```
val adj1value = htAdjId.find(_._2 == value1).getOrElse(default)._1
```

but that gives me only the first key "large" (as is the [definition](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.5.1/scala/List.html#find%28%28A%29%3D%3EBoolean%29) of find). I searched a lot but I am not able to find a "findall" function. Does it exist in Scala? If not, can someone please advice me on how to solve this problem?

Comment: use `filter` instead. `find` stops at the first match

Comment: When you say forall I think of `Traversable.forall(p: A => Boolean): Boolean` Which I dont think is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the collection and extract all keys using `keys`:

```
val map = Map("h" -> 27, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 27)
map.filter { case (key, value) => value == 27 }.keys
```

Yields

```
res0: Iterable[String] = Set(h, c)
```

Though I'd argue that if you need to iterate the entire `Map` each time, perhaps it isn't the right data structure to begin with, perhaps a `List[(String, Int)]` will suffice and save the overhead incurred by using a `Map`.

Comment: I agree with the last paragraph. If lookup is always this way, then the `Map` is simply the wrong way round. (It would need to be a `Multimap` in the other direction, though.) If lookup is needed in both directions, a `BidiMap` (aka `BiMap`) or more precisely a `MultiBiMap` / `MultiBidiMap` / `BiMultiMap` / `BidiMultiMap` (or whatever it is called) would be the data structure of choice. (Actually, the data structure is a bidirectional relation, like a SQL table.)

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the map as a Iterable[K,V] then groupBy the value like this..

```
@ Map(
    "large" -> 27,
    "indispensable" -> 27,
    "most" -> 27
).groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.keys)

res4: Map[Int, Iterable[String]] = Map(27 -> Set(
  "large",
  "indispensable",
  "most"))
```

Comment: The answer assumes all values are equal to 27, which I also assume myself isn't the real case.

Answer (score 0):

[answered by a friend of mine offline] Hashmaps are usually built to do only the forward lookup efficiently. Unless you know that the underlying data structure used in the hashmap supports this, you probably don't want to do this "reverse lookup" because it will be *very* inefficient.

Consider putting your data into a [bi-directional map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850786/is-there-such-a-thing-as-bidirectional-maps-in-scala%20stackoverflow.com) or "bi-map" from the start if you are going to access it in both directions. OR, use [two hashmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678970/what-is-the-most-succinct-scala-way-to-reverse-a-map%20stackoverflow.com): one in regular direction, one inverted (values become keys, keys become values) OR use different data structure altogether.

i.e two maps is a good idea if the map is large or you're going to be doing this kind of check a lot.  Otherwise try filter instead of find

Comment: [I asked him] my values are not unique. So will a bi-directional map work? Shouldnt the values and keys also be unique to use guava's bimap?

Comment: [his reply] Then a bi-directional map probably won’t work. If you’re just doing the reversal once, you might try groupBy, as in `val value2adj = htAdjId.groupBy{ case (k, v) => v }.map{ case (k, v) => k -> v.map(_._1) }` 
That would give you a map from values to a list of keys having that value, which you can then use `getOrElse` on. There’s probably even a shortcut to do this.